# Send a picture of a map through email in Android

Tags: java, android, email, google-maps

In my app I locate the location of the user and give them the option to send it through email.
The only thing i send is the Maps url. Now i want 'spice' the email up and add a little picture of the map (with a marker for the location) to the mail.

I googled but couldn't find a way to do this.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked some more into this and found this:
http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=52.390082,4.890145&zoom=14&size=320x200&markers=52.390082,4.890145

It's a .gif file with exact the same image i was going for.

Only, how can i add this as a gif to an email? When i just insert the link, it looks like a link (duh). I want it to appear as a picture.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Section 10.8 of the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) forbids that.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with a standard embed in a HTML e-mail TBH.

Comment: I read it as wanting to attach an image of the map to the email.

Comment: There are a lot of apps that already do this, so I don't really see a problem.